# How to combine two tables in Sql Server which contains different column names but holds similar information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had two tables T1 and T2.

T1 contains columns as `p_latitude` and `p_longitude` and `year` (2014,2013,2012,2011)

T2 contains columns as `latitude` and `longitude` and `p_year`(2015).

How should I combine these two tables T1 and T2 and show information for all the years in the following format...`Year,Latitude,Longitude`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the columns have the same type:

```
SELECT p_latitude latitude, p_longitude longitude, year
FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT latitude, longitude, p_year year
FROM T2
```

Otherwise you have to cast one to the other

EDIT: Changed UNION to UNION ALL due to better performances

Comment: It should use UNION ALL. It says "show information for all years", not distinct information

Comment: @JulienVavasseur You would be right if there was overlapping years: from what I've understood reading the specs there are no double years

Comment: UNION removes duplicate records, whereas UNIONALL does not. Not a big difference in my issue. Anyways its a good suggestion.

Comment: SQL Server will order the data and look for duplicate anyhow if UNION is used without ALL. You may have the desired output but it will have an impact on performance.

Comment: Being honest, in some cases it could; of course it depends on the environment and needing and this case seemed not to be affected by this